# how to enforce case property name on proto generation for go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a user message as such :

```
message User {
    string uid = 1;
}
```

Protobuff generates a struct as such

```
type User struct {
    Uid string
}
```

Is there a way to enforce destination case so that my user struct in Go would be like :

```
type User struct {
    UID string
}
```

So far, I can use `string uID` in my proto definition but it feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be supported.
As listed in [`golang/protobuf` issue 555](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/555)

> By convention, naming styles are different:
>
> - Protos uses CamelCase for messages, groups, enums, services, and methods
> - Protos uses snake_case for fields and oneof fields
> - Protos uses SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE for enum values
> - Go uses CamelCase for everything

So for now, `uID` is the best workaround.